# Action binding ignores inherited properties (API)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[ResponseType(typeof(PlanningRestGet))]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody] PlanningRestPut model)
{
    return CallAndPrepareResponse(c => c.UpdatePlanning(id, model));
}
```

I've created a new "BaseRestPut" class with two new properties, and made PlanningRestPut class inherit it.

But now when the action is executed, the properties from the base class are null in the model object.

I've read this https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/webapi-data-binding.html but it looks like in my case I don't want to pass the base class as an argument, but the derived class (and keep the properties from the base class as well.)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This was because my base class was missing the [DataContract] decorator.